# Firebase Remote Config Cache Expiration Handling

Tags: firebase, firebase-remote-config

**Issue Summary**

We're seeing some issues in our app where some users launch the app and see the default config values instead of the ones expected. Restarting the application fixes the issue for those users and they see the correct values as expected.

**Longer Description**

We're using Strategy #3 as described here. https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/01/firebase-remote-config-loading.html

On launch, we first do `activateFetched` and then do `fetch`, with nothing in the completion handler.

Sometimes, after `activateFetched` RemoteConfig falls back to default values even though they were seeing the correct values on the previous launch. Restarting the app and calling `activateFetched` fixes this issue and we see the correct expected values.

To me, it looks like the RemoteConfig cache is expiring at some point and falls back to default values instead. Desired behavior is that we always use the cached values and fetch new ones the first chance we get.

We would love some input about the best way for us to be handling cache expiration for Firebase Remote Config.

Comment: Hi @Dhaval were you able to resolve the issue?\